# Response is undefined in promise.then() for nested object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, axios, redux-thunk

I'm experiencing strange behaviour in redux dispatch. For dispatch function res is undefined however for console log one line above that function call res is properly logged. Any ideas why this is happenning?

**main action**

```
export const uploadFiles = (files: File[], artworkId: string, fileType: string) => (
    (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
        files.forEach(file => {
            axios.post(
                `${my-api-route}, convertToFormDataFile(file, fileType))
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res.data.data.id) //works
                    dispatch(uploadFileLimitedEditionSuccess(res.data.data.id, file, fileType))
                }) //does not work
                .catch(err => dispatch(uploadFileLimitedEditionFailure(err.response.data.errors[fileType === 'pdf' ? 'pdf' : 'file'], file.name, fileType)))
        })
    }
);
```

**success action**

```
const uploadFileLimitedEditionSuccess = (id: any, file: File, fileType: string):LimitedEditionActionType => ({
    type: LIMITED_EDITIONS_UPLOAD_FILE_SUCCESS,
    payload: {
        id,
        file,
        fileType
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure `res.data.data.id` is correct? Can you show the content of res?

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:javascript], but that looks more like [tag:typescript]

Comment: Yes, sorry I've Just corrected message in console.log. This one prints correctly. I know this is Typescript but error does not come from typings therefore I assumed js tag would be better.

Comment: Just console.log(res) and make sure u are accessing props correctly or even better, destruct them.

Comment: Yes, the response have all properties. Case is that dispatch is losing res object somehow. What's more, looking in the debugger I've found that it should have acces to that object.

Comment: Use lodash library's get method, it will help you get through it. i.e. `get(res, 'data.data.id', null);`

For reference: [https://lodash.com/docs/#get]

Answer (score 0):

If the object reference is lost, just pass in the value. Also, check the value you are passing in to `dispatch` - it needs to be an object (see https://redux.js.org/api/store/#dispatchaction)

```
export const uploadFiles = (files: File[], artworkId: string, fileType: string) => (
    (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
        files.forEach(file => {
            axios.post(
                `${my-api-route}, convertToFormDataFile(file, fileType))
                .then(res => {
                    console.log('I got called!)
                    console.log(res)
                    console.log(res.data.data.id) //works
                    const id = res.data.data.id
                  const toDispatch = uploadFileLimitedEditionSuccess(id, file, fileType)
                  console.log(toDispatch)
                  dispatch(toDispatch)
                }) //does not work
                .catch(err => {
               console.log(err)
dispatch(uploadFileLimitedEditionFailure(err.response.data.errors[fileType === 'pdf' ? 'pdf' : 'file'], file.name, fileType))
          })
        })
    }
);
```

Comment: I've tried this before and this doesn't work. Also, I've  put variable(response value) in console.log and it log worked but dispatch didnt

Comment: The problem may be in `uploadFileLimitedEditionSuccess` then...

Comment: As far as I know `uploadFileLimitedEditionSuccess` is not invoked until its arguments are not fully evaluated.

Comment: dispatch takes an object as its argument: https://redux.js.org/api/store/#dispatchaction. What is the return value of `uploadFileLimitedEditionSuccess`?

Comment: it is an object with type and payload
`const uploadFileLimitedEditionSuccess = (id: any, file: File, fileType: string):LimitedEditionActionType => ({
    type: LIMITED_EDITIONS_UPLOAD_FILE_SUCCESS,
    payload: {
        id,
        file,
        fileType
    }
});`

Comment: And if you log it out as in my suggestion above (I edited it)? I'm sure that code would work, or reveal the problem.

Comment: So action creator got the id from response object however still getting the same error.

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined. It points to the line above catch (where are closing brackets only)

Comment: It is probably from another invocation, not the current one. Try the updated edit.

Comment: I'm passing single value array.

Comment: Yes, but some assumption may be incorrect, so (in)validate them all, by logging. It could be the reference to `error.response.data` in the catch block that is throwing. Log all the things.

Comment: thanks for the tip. Actually after putting console.log in catch block I've found that there was somewhere non-object passed to function which required object. After further research I've found that it was Object.entries in my reducer.